# rendering plotly dash in Django template

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I am using https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to serve my plotly dash in Django. At the moment the chart is rendered ok in my template. However, it displays very small, I try to adjust the size of the div but it doesn't seem to work.

```html
{%load plotly_dash%}


<div style="height: 100%; ">
 {%plotly_app name="simple_example" %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed with the help of [Github Doc](https://djangoplotlydash.com/demo-eight/)

```html
{%load plotly_dash%}

 <div class="{% plotly_class name="simple_example"%}">

   {% plotly_app name="simple_example" ratio=1 %}

</div>
```